# Docker Desktop not working with local CNTLM proxy

Tags: windows, proxy, docker, ntlm, cntlm

I'm, having trouble to set up my local dev environment. I want to use Docker Desktop in my Windows 10 machine behind a local CNTLM proxy.

My CNTLM Proxy works. This is the output after I start my CNTLM

```
0 [main] cntlm 17620 find_fast_cwd: WARNING: Couldn't compute FAST_CWD pointer.  Please report this problem to
the public mailing list cygwin@cygwin.com
section: global, Username = 'pd03056'
section: global, Domain = 'Provinzial'
section: global, Proxy = '192.168.10.10:80'
section: global, NoProxy = 'localhost, 127.0.0.*, 10.*, 192.168.*'
section: global, Listen = '0.0.0.0:3128'
Resolve 0.0.0.0:
  -> 0.0.0.0
cntlm: Proxy listening on 0.0.0.0:3128
Adding no-proxy for: 'localhost'
Adding no-proxy for: '127.0.0.*'
Adding no-proxy for: '10.*'
Adding no-proxy for: '192.168.*'
cntlm: Workstation name used: L00265511WP
cntlm: Using following NTLM hashes: NTLMv2(1) NT(0) LM(0)
Password:
cntlm: PID 17620: Cntlm ready, staying in the foreground
```

I confimed that this works from a local WSL instance doing a `curl www.google.de`. I have a local ~/.curlrc file pointing curl to my CNTLM.

```
$ more ~/.curlrc
-x 127.0.0.1:3128
cacert = /path/to/my/trusted-certs.pem

$ curl www.google.de
# I skip the whole output here ...
# The CNTLM log shows that it communicates with google.de
# and I ger the correct result in WSL
```

Now here is my problem ... My Docker Desktop installation (version 4.4.4 [73704]) should use this proxy as well. I configured Docker Desktop to do so by putting `http://host.docker.internal:3128` as HTTP and HTTPS proxy in Settings -> Resources -> Proxies. But I always get an error.

`docker run` from my *Windows* terminal results in this message

```
PS C:\Users\pd03056> docker run -it --rm hello-world:latest
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": remote error: tls: handshake failure.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

The CNTLM log does not state anything either. So Docker Desktop does not use my CNTLM! `host.docker.internal` resolves to a correct IP of my workstation. Putting `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` instead of `host.docker.internal` does not change anything.

Anyone got an idea why my Docker Desktop installation does not pick up the Proxy config?

Comment: I suggest you check with Wireshark what Docker Desktop is doing on the network. Note that it may be local traffic that is only visible on the virtual loopback capture adapter. // Docker also has debug logging that you can enable.

Comment: Does it work if you set the HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY environment variables instead?

Comment: Still same error message with the environment variables.